# malloc incorrect checksum for freed object, - object was probably modified after being freed.Abort trap: 6

Tags: c++, malloc

```
foo(){

    Network net(*this); 


    for(int u=0 ; u<Vertices.size() ; u++){         //for every vertex u
    vector<Edges> NeighborsOfu = Vertices[u].adjacencyList; //tmp vector for edge delete


    for(int v=0; v<Vertices[u].adjacencyList.size(); v++){  //for each neighbor v of u
        int indexV = Vertices[u].adjacencyList[v].pointsTo;  //index V = index of neighbor node v in Vertices

        for(int w=0; w<Vertices[u].adjacencyList.size(); w++){  //for each neighbor of u, check if neighbor of 
            cout<<"topocontrol::INSIDE FIRST FOR (before b_search)\n";
            //vindexOfW = index of node W in AL of node V, -1 if not found
//************************HERE IS WHERE IT BREAKS DOWN**********************//
            int vIndexOfW = al_bSearch(Vertices[indexV].adjacencyList, 
                         Vertices[u].adjacencyList[w].pointsTo); //search v's AL for w


//*************************UP THERE***************************************//
            cout<<"After BSearch (before 2nd if) \n";

                //if w was found in v's AL 
                if(vIndexOfW!= -1){ cout<< "INSIDE SECOND IF  (if w is a common neighbor) \n"; //if u's neighbor w is found in v's AL

                    //check if weight of edge |uw| < |uv|
                    if(Vertices[u].adjacencyList[w].weight < Vertices[u].adjacencyList[v].weight){
                    //check if weight of edge |vw| < |uv| 
                        cout<<"INSIDE THIRD IF (if |uw|<|uv|\n";
                        if(Vertices[indexV].adjacencyList[vIndexOfW].weight < Vertices[u].adjacencyList[v].weight){
                        cout<< "NOW ERASE \n";
                        int l = al_bSearch(NeighborsOfu, indexV); //to compensate for erase() moving remaining elements, must make sure you erase the correct one, whose index possibly changed in prev iterations
                        NeighborsOfu.erase(NeighborsOfu.begin()+l);
                    }
                }       
            }
            cout<<"after nested ifs\n";

        }
    }
cout<< "REPLACING NEIGHBOR LIST\n\n";   
    net.Vertices[u].adjacencyList = NeighborsOfu;
}

return net;
}
```

I'm attempting to implement a network topology control protocol for an assignment, but as the number of nodes grows, the program starts giving me the error in the title, accompanied by two hex memory addresses. Until now the error has popped up when the binary search is finished and attempts to return the items index (sorting takes place elsewhere in code). I'm not using free() anywhere in the code, and the only pointers used are for the copy constructor (*this), and in main(), wherer there is an array of pointers to instances of objects. I could use some help finding its cause, I've been at this for a couple of days and still can't find it.

edit:the network class is inheriting most of its members from a previously made myGraph class.

```
class wirelessNetwork : public myGraph {

public:
wirelessNetwork();
wirelessNetwork(float, int);
void setPosX(float, int);
void setPosY(float, int);
float vertexDistance(int, int);
wirelessNetwork topologyControl();
bool compassRouting(int, int, std::vector<int>& );

protected:
float size;
int n;
```

};

```
struct Edges{
        float weight;
        int pointsTo;
    };
 class Vertex{
   public:
   string data;
   float posX;
   float posY;
   vector<Edges> adjacencyList;
 Vertex() {};
 Vertex(string st) { data = st;}
 void setPosX(float x){posX = x;}
 void setPosY(float y){posY = y;}
 }; // end of Vertex struct

class myGraph{
  public: 
    /recieve vertex, return vector containing pointsTo indexes
vector<int> getNeighborsOf(int);
  //delete edges between 2 nodes
  void deleteEdge(int, int);
  //delete node and all connected edges
  void deleteVertex(int);
  int al_bSearch(vector<Edges>, int) const;

//get average node degree of graph. if parameter is received it leaves equal  
float getAverageDegree();
float getAverageDegree(int&);


protected:
/***** Data Member *****/
vector<Vertex> Vertices;
```

Comment: If you're using C++, you shouldn't be needing to use `malloc()` at all. There isn't a reference to `malloc()` in the code AFAICS, so your C++ implementation may build `new` etc on top of `malloc()`. The system is trying to tell you that you've written outside the bounds of allocated memory (written out of bounds in one of your arrays or possibly one of your vectors). I strongly recommend using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to resolve the problems if that's an option for you.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion your nodes for your `adjacencyList[]` are not properly implementing [RO3-semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)). If not those, than something else, but it is not-at-all uncommon to see this specific error when that is the case. Run this through valgrind if it is supported on your platform. And regardless, post the full class-decls for the classes listed in this code. We can do very little without knowing what we're working with.

Comment: I don't use malloc, I'm looking up Valgrind now, and the adjacencyList is really a vector containing the weight of the edge and the index of the node it points to. I didn't make them a destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator